# location-tracking using map

Tags: cordova, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm trying to build phonegap app to track vehicle based on their mobile gps data. I went through google map API page and found the below

- Google Maps Directions API
- Google Maps Distance Matrix API
- Google    Maps Elevation API
- Google Maps Geocoding API
- Google Maps Geolocation    API
- Google Maps Roads API
- Google Maps Time Zone API
- Google Places API Web Service

Out of all these API I feel **google map Roads API** is the possible choice for me but, the demo is not looks like what I wants to build...

Can anyone advice me or direct me to the right direction....

My goal is to build an app for tracking the path a vehicle travel on map...

Answer (score 1):

@Ferdinand,

you want *geolocation*, or Actually *reverse-geolocation*. The information you need is spread across Google's documentation for geolocation and few other libraries.

I have built the same App as you. It is one of my demo apps.
Feel free to use as much or as little as you need. It is part of a tutorial.

- [Seven (7) Simple Google Map Examples in one mobile app., A quick tutorial](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/phonegap/googleMapExamples/phonegap/oFNGXE46HHM/1nSdtvyBAQAJ) - Announcment
- [Google Map Examples](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples/wiki) Tutorial
- [Google Map Examples](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/googleMapExamples) code

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with the [cordova-plugin-googlemaps plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps). It says it works with phonegap.

The plugin has the ability to get the [gps location](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Location/README.md) and it lets you [draw a line (Polyline)](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Polyline/README.md) on the map.

It has [great documentation](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/README.md) and is very similar to the google maps apis.